# How can I show two users what taxonomy terms they have selected in common?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users, panels

I have a taxonomy vocabulary, **Hobbies**.  Users can select their hobbies from a list of about 300.  Many users select a few dozen hobbies, which makes for an extremely long list.

What I'd like to do is show a special list of those hobbies that the logged-in user has in common with the user being viewed.

I'm using Panels to override the user profile page, so I can easily attach views/content panes, blocks, etc.  I also have access to the logged-in user and the user being viewed through Panels contexts.

Is it possible to use Views to filter out taxonomy values in this way?  If not, how might I show users those terms that they have in common?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Taxonomy Filter](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_filter) module

> if vocabulary A is set to be 'filtered' by vocabulary B (which may be
>   vocabulary A), then whenever someone views the taxonomy listing of a
>   term in vocabulary A they will see a 'filter' menu of terms from
>   vocabularies A and B. This allows the visitor to narrow down the
>   listing by choosing another term - effectively showing them the
>   ***intersection*** set of nodes from the two terms.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I installed the module and attempted to configure it; however, it appears this module is for filtering searches based on taxonomy terms by modifying the views taxonomy path.  In my case, however, users have a list of hobbies (an unlimited term reference) which is saved in their profiles, and I'd like to show this on the user profile page.